# erro quando vou pesquisar o cliente

Tags: c

eu fiz esse programa meu problema está sendo em pesquisar o cliente assim que eu pesquiso ele não me da o resultado e encerra o programa, gostaria de saber oque faço para sanar o problema

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>


typedef struct cliente CLIENTE;

struct cliente{
    unsigned long  id;
    char nome[50];
    char telefone[15];
    char cpf[12];
    char email[50];

};

void menu();
void cadastracliente();
void listarCliente();
void pesquisaCliente();

int main(){
    menu();
    return 0;
}

void menu(){

    int escolha;
    do{
        system("cls");
        printf("[1]-cadastra Cliente\n");
        printf("[2]-listar Cliente\n");
        printf("[3]-Pesquisar Cliente\n");
        printf("[0]-Sair\n");
        printf(": ");
        scanf("%d",&escolha);
        switch(escolha){
        case 1:
            cadastracliente();
            break;
        case 2:
            listarCliente();
            break;
        case 3:
            pesquisaCliente();
            break;
        }

    }while(escolha!=3);
}

void cadastracliente(){
    system("cls");
    FILE* arquivo;
    CLIENTE clt;

    arquivo = fopen("cliente.dat","ab");
    if(arquivo ==NULL){
        printf("Problemas na abertura do arquivo");
    }else{
        do{

            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Digite o nome: ");
            gets(clt.nome);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Digite o CPF: ");
            gets(clt.cpf);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Digite o email: ");
            gets(clt.email);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Digite o Telefone: ");
            gets(clt.telefone);

            fwrite(&clt,sizeof(CLIENTE),1,arquivo);

            printf("\nDeseja continuar(s/n)");

        }while(getch() =='s');
        fclose(arquivo);
    }
}


void listarCliente(){
    system("cls");
    FILE* arquivo;
    CLIENTE clt;

    arquivo = fopen("cliente.dat","rb");
    if(arquivo ==NULL){
        printf("Problemas na abertura do arquivo");
    }else{
        printf("---------------CLIENTES---------------\n");
        while(fread(&clt,sizeof(CLIENTE),1,arquivo)==1){

            printf("id: %lu\n",clt.id);
            printf("Nome: %s\n",clt.nome);
            printf("CPF: %s\n",clt.cpf);
            printf("E-mail: %s\n",clt.email);
            printf("Telefone: %s\n",clt.telefone);
            printf("--------------------------------------\n");
        }
    }
    fclose(arquivo);
    getch();

}

void pesquisaCliente(){
    system("cls");
    FILE* arquivo;
    CLIENTE clt;
    char nome[30];

    arquivo = fopen("cliente.dat","rb");
    if(arquivo ==NULL){
        printf("Problemas na abertura do arquivo");
    }else{
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Digite o nome a pesquisar: ");
        gets(nome);

        while(fread(&clt,sizeof(CLIENTE),1,arquivo)==1){
            if(strcmp(clt.nome,nome)==0){
                printf("id: %lu\n",clt.id);
                printf("Nome: %s\n",clt.nome);
                printf("CPF: %s\n",clt.cpf);
                printf("E-mail: %s\n",clt.email);
                printf("Telefone: %s\n",clt.telefone);
                printf("--------------------------------------\n");
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(arquivo);
    getch();
}

´´´
```

Comment: Não encontrei problema no seu codigo. Apenas essa linha ```while(escolha!=3);```. so substituir o 3 pelo 0, como indicado no meu.

Comment: muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem alguns problemas no código que estão fazendo ele se comportar assim.
A primeira coisa, como o Bernardo falou nos comentários é que você precisa trocar o `while(escolha!=3)` por `while(escolha!=0)` no loop principal. Isto vai corrigir o fluxo do menu.

A segunda coisa a verificar é que você não dá nenhuma indicação de que o cliente não foi encontrado. Então se você pesquisar por um cliente que não existe, nada acontece e o programa fica parado na tela, travado. Um flag pode resolver isso facinho, facinho.

```
char encontrado = 0;
while (fread(&clt, sizeof(Cliente), 1, arquivo) == 1) {
    if (strcmp(clt.nome, nome) == 0) {
        exibirCliente(&clt);
        encontrado = 1;
        break;
    }
}
if (!encontrado)
    printf("Cliente %s não encontrado.\n", nome);
```

Outra coisa é que, tal como está, o cliente só vai ser encontrado se você pesquisar pelo nome exatamente como ele foi cadastrado, levando em consideração letras maiúsculas, minúsculas, espaços e caracreres especiais. Se você prestar atenção, `fgets` está salvando no arquivo os textos com o caracter \n, então você vai precisar removê-lo dos campos do cliente antes de salvar. Uma função simples para fazer isso pode ser implementada com um loop:

```
void removerEnter(char* buffer, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (buffer[i] == '\n') {
            buffer[i] = '\0';
            return;
        }
    }
}

void ajustarCliente(Cliente* cliente) {
    removerEnter(cliente->nome, 50);
    removerEnter(cliente->telefone, 15);
    removerEnter(cliente->cpf, 12);
    removerEnter(cliente->email, 50);
}
```

e chamada antes de salvá-lo:

```
do {
    printf("Digite o nome: ");
    fgets(clt.nome, 50, stdin);

    printf("Digite o CPF: ");
    fgets(clt.cpf, 12, stdin);

    printf("Digite o email: ");
    fgets(clt.email, 50, stdin);

    printf("Digite o Telefone: ");
    fgets(clt.telefone, 15, stdin);

    ajustarCliente(&clt);
    fwrite(&clt, sizeof(Cliente), 1, arquivo);

    printf("\nDeseja continuar(s/n)\n");

} while (getch() == 's');
fclose(arquivo);
```

Uma implementação completa com todas estas correções ficaraia mais ou menos assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct cliente {
    unsigned long id;
    char nome[50];
    char telefone[15];
    char cpf[12];
    char email[50];
};
typedef struct cliente Cliente;

void menu();
void cadastracliente();
void listarCliente();
void pesquisaCliente();

void exibirCliente(Cliente* cliente) {
    printf("id      : %lu\n", cliente->id);
    printf("Nome    : %s\n", cliente->nome);
    printf("CPF     : %s\n", cliente->cpf);
    printf("E-mail  : %s\n", cliente->email);
    printf("Telefone: %s\n", cliente->telefone);
}

void removerEnter(char* buffer, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (buffer[i] == '\n') {
            buffer[i] = '\0';
            return;
        }
    }
}

void ajustarCliente(Cliente* cliente) {
    removerEnter(cliente->nome, 50);
    removerEnter(cliente->telefone, 15);
    removerEnter(cliente->cpf, 12);
    removerEnter(cliente->email, 50);
}

int main() {
    menu();
    return 0;
}

void menu() {
    int escolha;
    do {
        system("cls");
        printf("[1]-cadastra Cliente\n");
        printf("[2]-listar Cliente\n");
        printf("[3]-Pesquisar Cliente\n");
        printf("[0]-Sair\n: ");
        fscanf(stdin, "%d%*c", &escolha);
        switch (escolha)
        {
        case 1:
            cadastracliente();
            break;
        case 2:
            listarCliente();
            break;
        case 3:
            pesquisaCliente();
            break;
        }
    } while (escolha != 0);
}

void cadastracliente()
{
    system("cls");
    FILE* arquivo;
    Cliente clt;

    arquivo = fopen("cliente.dat", "ab");
    if (arquivo == NULL)
    {
        printf("Problemas na abertura do arquivo");
        return;
    }

    do {
        printf("Digite o nome: ");
        fgets(clt.nome, 50, stdin);

        printf("Digite o CPF: ");
        fgets(clt.cpf, 12, stdin);

        printf("Digite o email: ");
        fgets(clt.email, 50, stdin);

        printf("Digite o Telefone: ");
        fgets(clt.telefone, 15, stdin);

        ajustarCliente(&clt);
        fwrite(&clt, sizeof(Cliente), 1, arquivo);
        printf("\nDeseja continuar(s/n)\n");

    } while (getch() == 's');
    fclose(arquivo);
}

void listarCliente()
{
    system("cls");
    FILE* arquivo;
    Cliente clt;

    arquivo = fopen("cliente.dat", "rb");
    if (arquivo == NULL) {
        printf("Problemas na abertura do arquivo!");
        return;
    }

    printf("---------------CLIENTES---------------\n");
    while (fread(&clt, sizeof(Cliente), 1, arquivo) == 1) {
        exibirCliente(&clt);
        printf("--------------------------------------\n");
    }
    fclose(arquivo);
    getch();
}

void pesquisaCliente()
{
    system("cls");
    FILE* arquivo;
    Cliente clt;
    char nome[30];

    arquivo = fopen("cliente.dat", "rb");
    if (arquivo == NULL) {
        printf("Problemas na abertura do arquivo");
        return;
    }

    printf("Digite o nome a pesquisar: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(nome, 30, stdin);
    removerEnter(nome, 30);
    char encontrado = 0;
    while (fread(&clt, sizeof(Cliente), 1, arquivo) == 1) 
    {
        if (strcmp(clt.nome, nome) == 0) {
            exibirCliente(&clt);
            encontrado = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!encontrado)
        printf("Cliente %s não encontrado.\n", nome);
    fclose(arquivo);
    getch();
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Bons estudos!

Comment: Ajudou muito obrigado

Comment: Imagina... é um prazer.
Se tiver sanado sua dúvida, você poderia marcar a minha resposta como a correta? Valeu!

Comment: Como poderia fazer um cotador para ID do cliente?,para cliente ter um ID diferente do outro

Answer (score 0):

A condicao do while está errada, no codigo se você fazer uma pesquisa vai entrar no while e sair do loop

while(escolha!=0);

Só mudar a condicao para 0